# Video compression - DirectShow

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, compression, directshow

I'm generating a video (.AVI) that last about 1 minutes for 150MB of size on 320x240 mode.
The size is really big, and I can't upload it efficiently.

After the recording application has finished How could I compress the video without displaying a window?
I recently installed FFMPEG and with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -s 320x240 -vcodec msmpeg4v2 output.avi
```

I can take the video to 3MB! I must say fantastic!
But... How could I do this from the inside of my application?
It would really be better doing this while the application is recording, whiutout installing ffmpeg, and not after.

I'm now reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374572(v=vs.85).aspx
Is this the right page to read?

Comment: What does your filter graph look like? It sounds like you have no compression filter selected so it is just writing uncompressed frames into your avi file. You need to connect the output of your video sinnk to a compression filter and the output pin of this to one of the inputs of your avi muxer.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QqQe8exH Here is my code. Probably you are right, but in which part of my code should I create the filter?

Comment: I cannot view your pastebin as its private, however I think you need to read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375815(v=vs.85).aspx to understand how to construct the filter graph and add the filters at appropriate points.

Comment: Now you can read it, sorry! I have now listed all the filter I have on  my PC and there is also an MJPEG Compressor, could this work fine?

Comment: It would work but is not a great compression, you will get large files I seem to recall or poor video quality, you can test filter graphs and output files using http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/tools/monogram-graphstudio/. Basically you add your compression filter to your src filter, add the output from the compression filter to the avi muxer and the muxer to your file writer. So just create a compression filter and insert it at the correct place and it should work

Comment: So what filter do you raccomend?

Comment: Since you are using mp4 then h.264 would be fine but you need to install a directshow h.264 filter and muxer, free ones can be found [here](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/directshow-filters/) but I have never used them so cannot comment, good luck